# New Errors with Rmarkdown and pandoc-2.5 & 2.6 (cannot decode byte \xa9)

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I recently uploaded a new version of an R package in which the R markdown vignettes work well enough on my Ubuntu system with pandoc 2.2.

Today I was notified by R CRAN checking of the following

```
This version fails on both Fedora Linux and macOS with pandoc 2.5

--- re-building ‘Rmarkdown.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xa9': 
Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.streamDecodeUtf8With: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: processing vignette 'Rmarkdown.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
--- failed re-building ‘Rmarkdown.Rmd’

--- re-building ‘code_chunks.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
convert: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on 
grayscale PNG `tmpout/p-chunk65-1.png' @ 
warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1672.
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xa9': 
Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.streamDecodeUtf8With: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: processing vignette 'code_chunks.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
--- failed re-building ‘code_chunks.Rmd’

\xa9 is a Latin-1 copyright sign.  The PNG error is seen only on macOS.
Unfortunately knitr/pandoc produce no debugging information, so this is 
all I know.
```

Comment: One way to narrow it down would be to look for the `\xa9` byte using hexdump in the terminal: Does `hexdump -C Rmarkdown.Rmd | grep '\ba9\b'` output anything?

Comment: no, grepping for that does not find anything.  I truly believe it is just a red herring that is caused by the complicated tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the error about \xa9 is a wild goose chase.

The Pandoc instructions have changed.  Replacing this old stanza

```
header-includes:
-  \usepackage{xcolor}
-  \usepackage{fancybox}
-  \usepackage{calc}
-  \usepackage{subfig}
```

With this new one solved the problem.

````
header-includes:
- |
  ```{=latex}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{fancybox}
  \usepackage{calc}
  \usepackage{subfig}
  ```
````

After that, I do get a success with Pandoc 2.6.

At first I thought that I understood the problem, but then it happened again and I re-typed the new stanza entirely and Pandoc does not give the error anymore.  So I am *nonplussed*.

I have not yet found an answer for the PNG problem on Macintosh.